# Python define filename with string variable including '\'

Tags: python

I am using win32com to open a file from the MyDocument folder. It looks like this:

```
filename = (shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL, None, 0)) + '\fubar_sheet.xlsx'
```

This works great, but what I really want to do is make "fubar" a variable so that my function could open different filenames depending on circumstance. However the following does not work...

```
 filename = (shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL, None, 0)) + '\' + file_variable + '_sheet.xlsx'
```

... because python doesn't recognize that I've closed the quotes around the slash.

I assume there is a fix for this but I can't find it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Escape "\" as "\\".................

Comment: `
filename = (shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL, None, 0)) + '\file_variable' + '_sheet.xlsx'
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either escape `\` with another `\`:

```
filename = (shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL, None, 0)) + '\\' + file_variable + '_sheet.xlsx'
```

or you can make it a raw string literal to avoid having to escape `\`:

```
filename = (shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL, None, 0)) + r'\' + file_variable + '_sheet.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `os.path.join(...)`:

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import os

file_variable = 'fubar'
file_template = '{}_sheet.xlsx'

filename = os.path.join(
    shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL, None, 0),
    file_template.format(file_variable)
)

print(filename)
```

Which for me prints:

```
C:\Users\Andersen\Documents\fubar_sheet.xlsx
```

The nice thing about `join()` is that you can string many levels of the path together because it is implemented using the `*args` syntax. Meaning you can go

```
path = os.path.join(base_path, 'which', 'is', 'very', 'deep', 'fubar_sheet.xlsx')
```

Giving you `C:\Users\Andersen\Documents\which\is\very\deep\fubar_sheet.xlsx'`, AND it is OS agnostic, which means the slashes will behave differently on Mac/UNIX, e.g., `/home/andersen/which/is/very/deep/fubar_sheet.xlsx`.